# Getting data from a web service with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-http

Im trying to get data in a Json format from a remote WS using Angular and im having some trouble.
The data comes from the web service correctly but i cant use it inside the controller.
Why is that?
Angular Code:

```
var booksJson;
var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp',[]);

// get data from the WS
app.run(function ($http) {
    $http.get("https://SOME_API_PATH").success(function (data) {
        booksJson = data;
        console.log(data);  //Working
    });
});

app.controller('booksCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.data = booksJson;
    console.log($scope.data); //NOT WORKING
});
```

HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="booksCtrl">
<h2 ng-repeat="book in data">{{book.name}}</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: using a run block? why not a `.service` which returns a promise? then just simply `inject` that service in your `controller(s)`.

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi Why should i use a service?

Comment: @user4440845 You would use a service for many reasons. To name a few, dependency injection, modularity, maintainable, and provides a layer of abstraction. It depends though. If all you are ever going to do is receive a list of all books, then a service is overkill.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should put your $http.get inside your controller.

Also, the web service returns an object not an array. So your ng-repeat should be something like this: `book in data.books`

Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp', []);

app.controller('booksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("https://whispering-woodland-9020.herokuapp.com/getAllBooks")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<article ng-app="booksInventoryApp">
  <section ng-controller="booksCtrl">
    <h2 ng-repeat="book in data.books">{{book.name}}</h2>    
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Nice answer.                                                                                                                The .success method has now been depreciated. You should use the .then method now.                             https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @BenCameron ok, thanks. I have updated the answer with that change now.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `bookJSON` as array, and push the elements instead of assignment. So

`var bookJSON=[];`

Inside `$http.get` do

`data.forEach(function(item) { bookJSON.push(item); });`

The second console log will show undefined because, the call is async. The assignment happens in future.

The `run` method does not guarantee, that the code is run before controller loads.

There are other ways too to solve this issue.

Avoid global variable. Look at `$routeProvider` `resolve` property.

Or implement a service to get this data as promise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a run block you can use your $http service inside the controller, then attach your data to the scope like normal.  Just remember to inject the $http service into your controller.

```
app.controller('booksCtrl', function ($scope, $http) { 
    $http.get("https://whispering-woodland-9020.herokuapp.com/getAllBooks").success(function (data) {
        $scope.booksJson = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test your webservice</title>
</head>
<body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<article ng-app="booksInventoryApp">
  <section ng-controller="booksCtrl">
  </section>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp', []);

app.controller('booksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



                        //ResponseInvocationAgentRequestDTO 
                        var jsonObject = {
                                      "id":65,
                                      "idUserSender": 5}


                                    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            $http({
                method: 'put',             
                url: 'yout URI' ,
                data: jsonObject 
            })
            .success(function(data,status){
                console.log('all is good', data);

                })
                .error(function(data,status){
                    console.log('Erreur into url '+data);
                });


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```